# Any way to simplify integral of Confluent Hypergeometric Function of the First Kind?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

The integral is this:

$$\int_{-\log n}^{0}e^{t(1-s)} \cdot z \cdot {}_1F_1(1-z, 2, t) dt $$

Is there a way to write this in terms of special functions that eliminates the integral and doesn't use infinite sums either?

It can also be written as

$$-1+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{z}{k}(1-s)^{-k} P(k, (s-1)\log n)$$

where $P(a,z)$ is the regularized lower incomplete gamma function, if that is useful.  But I'd really like an expression that doesn't involve integrals or sums.

Comment: Is there a condition on "n"?  Real, Positive, negative?

Comment: Good question - I'm only concerned with n > 0 and real.

Comment: Well... I pretty much have the answer but haven't accommodated the e^(t(1-s)  correctly.  Are you in a hurry?

Comment: Cont: :)  Basically you take the Laplace transform divide by p (the target variable) and do the inverse xform.

Comment: Nope, I'm in no particular hurry.

Comment: In general I am a little stymied.  But I still have hope for exploiting Mellin transforms and the fact the b=2.
A list of general references is:
Eq 71 (the symbolic solution): in http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/74B/jresv74Bn2p85_A1b.pdf
And the Babister Lambda function is mention/written out in 
The last page of "Entire solutions of nonhomogenous differential equations"
The real reference is:
 Transcendental functions satisfying nonhomogeneous linear differential equations
On amazon (indirectly) for $12.00 which I am going to order.

Comment: Some progress but no cigar yet.  I have managed to derive the terms of a double Taylor series in (1-s),log(n) and the organization shows that the generating function type of expansion f(log(n),(1-s)=a_0(i-s)..a_n(1-s)(log(n))^n .... where a_n(1-s) is a sequence of polynomials forming a lower triangular coefficient array.      In any case I am working my way to collapsing the Taylor series to a closed generating function; but .. .  If your interested I can post, or point to, the present results.

Comment: You may have better luck using the change of variable $y=\frac{\log n}{t}+1$. This gives $dt=\frac{\log(n)dy}{y^2}$ and $t=-\log n\implies y=0$, $t=0\implies y=\infty$.

Then the integral becomes:
$$-z\log(n)\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{\frac{\log (n)(1-s)}{y-1}}}{(y-1)^2} {}_1F_1\left(1-z,2,\frac{\log n}{y-1}\right)dy.$$ There are plenty of tables of integrals with limits over $\mathbb{R}^+$. See e.g. Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, p.814.

Comment: @NathanMcKenzie out of interest, from what problem does this integral arise?

Comment: @pds Does it really useful for your approach? Your approach doesn't eliminate the effect of incomplete-type integral.

Comment: I have found a paper offering an analysis of this type of problem.  http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/74B/jresv74Bn2p85_A1b.pdf  I also have the referenced books if content is needed.

Comment: Yet another question:  How are you defining   
$\left(\begin{array}{c}z\\k\end{array}\right)$  for z real 
and P(0,x) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case $1$: $s=1$

Then $\int_{-\log n}^0z~_1F_1(1-z,2,t)~dt$

$=[-~_1F_1(-z,1,t)]_{-\log n}^0$ (according to http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/21/01/01)

$=~_1F_1(-z,1,-\log n)-~_1F_1(-z,1,0)$

$=~_1F_1(-z,1,-\log n)-1$

Case $2$: $s=2$

Then $\int_{-\log n}^0e^{-t}z~_1F_1(1-z,2,t)~dt$

$=\int_{-\log n}^0z~_1F_1(z+1,2,-t)~dt$ (according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Kummer.27s_transformation)

$=[-~_1F_1(z,1,-t)]_{-\log n}^0$ (according to http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/21/01/01)

$=~_1F_1(z,1,\log n)-~_1F_1(z,1,0)$

$=~_1F_1(z,1,\log n)-1$

Case $3$: $s\neq1,2$

Then $\int_{-\log n}^0e^{t(1-s)}z~_1F_1(1-z,2,t)~dt$

$=\int_{-\log n}^0\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\dfrac{z(1-z)_mt^me^{t(1-s)}}{(2)_mm!}dt$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^m\dfrac{(-z)_{m+1}t^ke^{t(1-s)}}{(m+1)!k!(s-1)^{m-k+1}}\right]_{-\log n}^0$ (according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions)

$=\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-z)_{m+1}}{(m+1)!(s-1)^{m+1}}-\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^m\dfrac{(-z)_{m+1}(-1)^k(\log n)^kn^{s-1}}{(m+1)!k!(s-1)^{m-k+1}}$

$=\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-z)_m}{m!(s-1)^m}-\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=k}^\infty\dfrac{(-z)_{m+1}(-1)^k(\log n)^kn^{s-1}}{(m+1)!k!(s-1)^{m-k+1}}$

$=\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-z)_m}{m!(s-1)^m}-1-\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-z)_{m+k}(-1)^k(\log n)^kn^{s-1}}{(m+k)!k!(s-1)^m}$

$=\left(1-\dfrac{1}{s-1}\right)^z-1+\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-z)_k(-1)^k(\log n)^kn^{s-1}}{(k!)^2}-\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-z)_{m+k}(-1)^k(\log n)^kn^{s-1}}{(m+k)!k!(s-1)^m}$ (according to http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F0/02)

$=\dfrac{(s-2)^z}{(s-1)^z}-1+n^{s-1}~_1F_1(-z,1,-\log n)-n^{s-1}\Phi_1\left(-z,1,1;\dfrac{1}{s-1},-\log n\right)$ (according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series)