# An incomplete double series: Is there a special functions representation?

Tags: special-functions

Consider the sum 
$$Q(v,u) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{l}\frac{u^l}{l!}  \frac{v^k}{k!}$$
[which arises from the inverse Laplace transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303947/closed-form-for-an-infinite-series-involving-lower-incomplete-gamma-functions) of $f(s) = \frac{1}{s(s-a)}e^{b/s}.$

Is there a means to express $Q(v,u)$ in terms of some special functions? It seems to be some sort of incomplete Humbert series like
$$ \Phi_3(\beta,\gamma,x,t) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\beta)_m}{(\gamma)_{m+n}m!n!}x^my^n$$ in that it has the wrong summation limits.
Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

As I showed
in my answer to
your other question
[Closed form for an infinite series involving lower incomplete gamma functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303947/closed-form-for-an-infinite-series-involving-lower-incomplete-gamma-functions),

$Q(u, v)+Q(v, u)
=e^{u+v}+I_0(2\sqrt{uv})
$.

I also suggested that
you research the
Marcum Q-function.

Comment: Thanks @marty. This is an alternate representation which helps me a lot. I did not find much of an analogue with the Marcum Q yet, but will research more today.

Comment: Update: Temme 1996 special functions book carefully outlines this function and highlights its relation to the $\chi^2$ distribution. This is definitely going to be the way forward. Thanks Marty. I will update with a solution shortly in case anyone else comes across such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum\limits_{l=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^l\dfrac{u^lv^k}{l!k!}$

$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{l=k}^\infty\dfrac{u^lv^k}{l!k!}$

$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{l=0}^\infty\dfrac{u^{l+k}v^k}{(l+k)!k!}$

$=\Phi_3(1,1;u,uv)$ (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series)